# Start Java Web Start application in java application with same JVM?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

this application starts a Java Web Start application. But it will start in a own JVM. The Standard JVM from the System! I looking for a way for starting the JWS-Application into the same JVM like this application. So that the java version and everything else is the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final File jnlp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".jnlp");
        final URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Test.jnlp");
        yourCopyStreamMethodYouWrote(url.openStream(), new FileOutputStream(jnlp));

        Desktop.getDesktop().open(jnlp);
    } catch (final Throwable t) {
        // do something useful here
    }
}

private static void yourCopyStreamMethodYouWrote(InputStream openStream, FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) throws IOException {
    IOUtils.copy(openStream,fileOutputStream);
    openStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: *"So that the java version and everything else is the same."*  .. Why?

Comment: If you want to execute something in the current JVM, you don't use JWS.  Simply have the jars in your application's classpath and call the desired methods.

Comment: Thank you but it is not possible to work with the jar file. The application is on a Server (i can not change anything) and on the client are different versions of java. So i must start the application with different versions of java (it doesnt work with a batch/javaws.exe because everytime the application take some functions from the primary version and i get some errors). I can not change the java configuration on the client, i can only change the application call. So now i looking for something for call the jnlp file into the application and same JVM.